# Creating a daemon that pipes output from one programme to another under systemd?

Tags: raspbian-buster, systemd

The system is a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) and using systemd.

I had expected this to be a trivial exercise but it is appearing to be less so than expected.  I have a USB SDR receiver than is set up to pass a stream of data through a third party programme (written in C) that strips data and then deposits it in an RRD as well as a second flat text file that aggregates all data received.

Essentially the data is being broadcast by an Energy monitor (Efergy) which broadcasts on Bluetooth a pulse every 6 seconds at 433.5MHz that is a reading of the amount of energy being consumed at that point in time. This data is collected by a separate (physically independent monitor) that aggregates the data and displays the amount of energy consumed at the time and over certain time frames (day, week, month etc).   It seemed to me this would be an ideal project for a Pi to collect the data into a form that can be more easily displayed in graphic form and displayed on a webpage similar to data I am aggregating from a number of temperature sensors around 2 locations.

What is different to the latter is that the data is broadcast continuously and the rtl-sdr listening programme needs to be run continuously.  Temperature measurements can be run intermittently through crontab.  The process works fine using the cli using a command such as (method 1)

`rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 7.7 2>/dev/null | ./Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt`

The output of the RTL-SDR is then piped into the C programme (originally written by Nataniel Elijah then adapted by Dr Li Gough and myself) which calculates the actual data required and writes this to a round-robin database (rrdtool by Oetiker) as well as a flat text file.  My 2 adaptions create a momentary system command through Energy_Log to run the rrdtool command that inserts the datapoint at the specified unixtime each time a new datapoint is received, or 'heard'.  I admit it would make more sense using the rrdtool 'C' library to do this directly but it works and I couldn't get the 'C' compiler to accept the rrdtool commands.

When run in the above form `ps -axf` shows the structure of the programme call as:-

```
12857 ?        S      0:00  |   \_ sshd: pi@pts/0
12860 pts/0    Ss     0:01  |       \_ -bash
13010 pts/0    Sl+    0:41  |           \_ rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 7.7
13011 pts/0    S+     0:02  |           \_ ./Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt
```

Here the ssh terminal runs a bash process which runs 2 programmes concurrently one the rtl_fm programme which then pipes the output to the concurrent Energy_Log programme.  Checking that the output is being sent to the Samples.txt file using `tail` shows:-

```
20201031_17:13:40     754.277344
20201031_17:13:46     758.554688
20201031_17:13:52     775.693359
20201031_17:13:58     750.000000
20201031_17:14:04     745.693359
```

ie at 5:14pm and 4secs on the 31st October 2020 the monitor was reading 745.7 watts of instantaneous consumption.  Well I suppose more correctly the house is drawing 3.107A of current at 240VAC.  This works fine as long as I always want to run the programme from an open terminal or ssh terminal. However as with all of my monitoring Pi's, my real aim is to have the process run like a daemon without a specific attached terminal.  I thought this would be relatively simple but then realised that the change to systemd introduces some complexity that I don't think were there previously.  Specifically it seems impossible to run a simple one line bash script that 'pipes' the output of one programme into the input of another.

Method 2,
Creating a service script in `/etc/systemd/system` called `rtlsdr.service` that contains the commands:-

```
Description=RTLTCP
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 19.7 2>&1 | /home/pi/Energy/Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Killing the properly constituted programme running in a terminal window above and then running the command `sudo systemctl start rtlsdr.service` does start a daemon but it runs as a single line bash command producing the `ps axf` shown below:-

```
12839 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
12842 ?        S      0:00  \_ (sd-pam)
13629 ?        Ssl    0:21 /usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 19.7 2>&1 | /home/pi/Energy/Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt
```

At least these seem to be the 3 lines of interest.  Now it maybe that I am missing something in the construction of the command as a pipe, **if so what is it?**  When I look at what is essentially the logfile, `Samples.txt`, I see the last written value as that when I killed the prior process and the round-robin db has this as a last accessed time as well.

In trying to get it working I came across a number of references to the fact that it is not possible to do what I was after with `systemd` even to the point that somebody had created a specific programme to do this which is part of a number of linux distributions including Debian that runs on the Raspberry Pi (see https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/pipexec).  What is a problem is that there seem to be few people that have implemented it and, though the help file associated with the github entry is quite explicit (see https://salsa.debian.org/alteholz/pipexec/-/blob/master/README.md) I'm still having problems working out whether I have the command correct or not.  As it stands the new systemd service file looks like (method 3):-

```
Description=RTL-SDR output from Efergy Monitor
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pipexec -l 7 -- [ RTL /usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 7.7 2>&1 ]  |  [ ELOG /home/pi/Energy/Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt ] '{RTL:1>ELOG:0}' 7>/var/log/rtl.log
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

NB the double dash is important as you are apssing the entire balance of the line to the command as an argument. Yes it was originally wrong so when started the usual `ps axf` command shows:-

```
14075 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/pipexec -l 7 [ RTL /usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 7.7 2>&1 ] | [ ELOG /home/pi/Energy/Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt ] {RTL 1>ELOG 0} 7>/var/log/rtl.log
14077 ?        Sl     0:03  \_ /usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 7.7 2>&1
14078 ?        S      0:00  \_ /home/pi/Energy/Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt
```

which is ok and output occurs as expected.  Logfile (/var/log/rtl.log) is chmod 777, output files chmod 776, obviously the programmes have execute access.    Anybody out there used `pipexec`?

Repeating the system is a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

Comment: As per meuh's answer, you need to consider what is parsing what.  Stuff like `|` and `2>&1` are elements in a specific language; they certainly don't mean the same thing in a C program as on the command line -- which "command line" is ambiguous, more specifically that stuff is POSIX shell.  If you know C, you probably can make a pretty good guess about how `|` or `2>&1` could be implemented in that context, which means you have some idea of *what they actually mean*.

Comment: ...You can reproduce this desired behaviour in a systemd unit file, but you have to learn the syntax/protocol of such  -- although an equally conventional approach here would be to wrap that whole `ExecStart` line in a shell script, in which you can use `|` and `>&` and such.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer from **meuh** is right but perhaps using pipexec is better.  Ultimately I discovered a minor error in the pipexec command which when fixed ran exactly the way I wished it to (the command in the post above is now corrected).  This has now been running for the best part of 2 years with information being written to an Oetiker RRD through a shell command (rather than trying to get the actual RRD 'C' library to work in perl).  It was just easier that way.

I've also set up a daily query of the rrd to send a daily power consumption figure in kWhrs to a Mariadb on my main server at just after midnight.  Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Very cryptic answer, hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

systemd does not do shell style parsing of the `ExecStart=` lines. See [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines). Typically, to have the pipe character and `2>&1` parsed by the shell, you will need to invoke the shell. Eg:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/rtl_fm ... 2>&1 | /home/pi/...'
```

Beware of using `$` and quotes in these lines, as systemd does parse them somewhat.

Comment: I suspect the redirection in the 2>&1 is also superfluous as it seems to have little impact if taken out in the original method.  I might just extract it and check the other 2 methods to see whether there is any improvement.  I'll also edit the question above to introduce a 'method #' for reference purposes.  Tim.

Comment: think we might have a winner!  your comment on the parsing of `2>&1` made me take it out and it seems to be working properly with the pipexec command (method 3).  I'll confirm after the first graph draw (every 15m) and after I drop the terminal window that ran the systemctl command then look at method 2 again.

Comment: yes, seems to work fine.  Now to exit both shells and leave it for a day.  Then check to see whether invoking a shell version of the original command is a simpler method to using pipexec although this seems to be working fine and may be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

For the files as the question was already answered, but IMHO some details were still missing.

As Tim Baker already wrote: In the command

```
/usr/bin/pipexec -l 7 -- [ RTL /usr/local/bin/rtl_fm -f 433500000 -s 200000 -r 96000 -g 7.7 2>&1 ]  |  [ ELOG /home/pi/Energy/Energy_Log /home/pi/Energy/Samples.txt ] '{RTL:1>ELOG:0}' 7>/var/log/rtl.log
```

you mix two concepts: `pipexec` does not parse or even understand something like `2>&1`. This is a shell (bash) notation redirection. With `pipexec` you use the syntax `{A:N>B:M}` to redirect. In your code, the string `2>&1` is passed as a parameter to `rtl_fm`.

In addition the `7>` is (still) a bash command which is not understood by `systemd` nor `pipexec`. A typical solution is using either `tee` or `ptee` here. Or you can use `-l s` to log directly to syslog / journald.

Note 1: it is not clear what you want to do with the stderr of the `rtl_fm` as in the shell command you discard it and it looks that in the `pipexec` command you want to handle the data?

Note 2: If you carefully read the logs of `pipexec` you can observe what happens here:

```
$ pipexec -l 2 -- '[ A /bin/true 2>&1 ]'
[...]
2022-06-21 07:16:19;pipexec;61897;0;command;info;command_info;[command]=[ A /bin/true 2>&1 ]];
```

Note 3: I'm the author of pipexec.

Comment: Andreas,  Thanx for your comments, I was grateful for your work on pipexec.  I have managed to get what I wanted working and to a point where it has been working  continuously for sometime without any interaction other than batteries on the transmitter wearing out, so I haven't even thought about it or this post for many months.  Coming across it when I was about to ask another question on a different subject.  I need to read your reply in  more depth to understand it and modify the commands, and try again but I'm away from this actual RPi for another 3 months so it will awhile yet.   Tim